# Can an external ip address on GAE be fixed on GAE with VPCConnector and CloudNAT?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, nat, vpc

Now, I would like to fix an ip address on GAE(Google App Engine) for an egress communication.

I checked this title at the both point of GAE and CloudRun.

On CloudRun, the ip address for egress could be fixed as showing below.

1. CloudRun
   Architectual:
   CloudRun + VPC Connector + Customerized VPC + Cloud NAT + Static external ip address

On the other hand, on GAE, above architecture was not same result.
Architectual:
GAE + VPC Connector + Customerized VPC + Cloud NAT + Static external ip address

According to below site, on this architecture on GAE, VPC Connector seems to be able to connect an
intenal ip address that something like Cloud NAT holds.

https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

I don't know why this difference happens.
Is there any related information, explainable information or reasons?

FYI:
In case of only GAE [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip]

Answer (score 3):

Today, the serverless VPC connector on GAE only route the internal traffic to it (compliant with RFC 1918). The public traffic doesn't go through the serverless VPC connector, so don't go through your VPC + Cloud NAT and you can't set a static IP on GAE for public IP.

You can use Cloud Run as reverse proxy to achieve this. Not very clean, but it's a possible solution. Or move your service from GAE to Cloud RUn.

Comment: Thank you for your information.

Not very clean, but possible, to use Cloud Run for it.